# About changing longitude array from 0 - 360 to -180 to 180 with Python xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am a matlab user trying to use Python more for my computations recently. I am using xarray and  would like to change my longitude array from 0 - 360 to -180 to 180 of a geophysical field. But when I do that:

```
df=xr.open_dataset(ecmwf_winds.nc)
u10=df['u10']
lon=df['longitude']
lon = np.where(lon > 180, lon-360, lon)
[X,Y]=np.meshgrid(lon,df.latitude)
plt.contourf(X,Y,u10)
```

the contourplot turns out to messy with gaps, which does not make sense. Can anyone please help me with it. I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: you should covert the range of ALL you data to the new range, not just the ones above 180. so the line `lon = np.where(lon > 180, lon-360, lon)` should just be `lon=lon-180`

Comment: Thank you, but it does not seem to work. Its something to do with the field. However, somehow got around it. Thank you again.

Comment: @GergesDib that's not right at all. longitudes from (-180 to 180) are not (0 to 360) - 180. The formula the OP has is correct - the data simply has to be sorted before it can be plotted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign the values as you've done and then also sort the resulting DataArray along the new coordinate values:

```
lon_name = 'longitude'  # whatever name is in the data

# Adjust lon values to make sure they are within (-180, 180)
ds['_longitude_adjusted'] = xr.where(
    ds[lon_name] > 180,
    ds[lon_name] - 360,
    ds[lon_name])

# reassign the new coords to as the main lon coords
# and sort DataArray using new coordinate values
ds = (
    ds
    .swap_dims({lon_name: '_longitude_adjusted'})
    .sel(**{'_longitude_adjusted': sorted(ds._longitude_adjusted)})
    .drop(lon_name))

ds = ds.rename({'_longitude_adjusted': lon_name})
```

Comment: @Light_B's [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561230/3888719) should be the accepted answer. Use that instead!

Answer (score 29):

Another faster approach and much simpler approach without using `where` would be

```
 df.coords['lon'] = (df.coords['lon'] + 180) % 360 - 180
 df = df.sortby(df.lon)
```

Tip: For quick plotting, you can use Xarrays inbuilt plotting function so you won't have to create a meshgrid.

```
df.u10.plot()
#or
df.u10.plt.contourf()
```

Comment: Note that the one-line solution *does not work*
 (because you sort before setting the new 'lon' values). The two lines solution works, thanks !

Comment: The vertical folding to center at 0 was a challenge. The `df.sortby(df.lon)` is simply brilliant and swift.

Comment: Works great but for netCDF data, it will lose the coordinate attributes. So I used `lon_atrib = df.coords['lon'].attrs` before processing and `df.coords['lon'].attrs = lon_atrib` after.

Comment: I have used this solution in the past and it worked, but now somehow if i do this and save the raster it gets upside down and loses the georeference.