# How to convert numpy.array to xarray.dataset in python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a satellite file which contains longitude within the range of (0,360) while I want to convert it to (-180,180).In order to do that I found a way here that is using xarray.where [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345442/about-changing-longitude-array-from-0-360-to-180-to-180-with-python-xarray) but this xr.where() only works well for " xarray dataset " and not "numpy.array". (After plotting there are some gaps in satellite orbit trajectories). So I would appreciate your favor if you can advise me how to convert the numpy array into xarray.dataset?

> ```
> #Reading the basic file
> type(orbit['lon']) >> numpyarray
> type(orbit['lat']) >> numpyarray
> etc.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here first part changes longitudes (180, 360) to negative and sorting orders the longitude in ascending order.

```
ds = ds.assign_coords(lon=(((ds.lon + 180) % 360) - 180)).sortby("lon")
```