# How do I reshape longitude data in an xarray of nc files

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

The current format of the longitude data is in the form (0,360) as shown in the picture. I want to get it to be (-180,180) where (-180,0) is equal to (180,360).

[image: code image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About changing longitude array from 0 - 360 to -180 to 180 with Python xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345442/about-changing-longitude-array-from-0-360-to-180-to-180-with-python-xarray)

Comment: also, please don't upload images of code, data, errors, etc when asking a question, for a [variety of reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, copy and paste your code, as well as the string representation of your xarray or pandas objects (e.g. the result of `print(ds)`) as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a column of longitude data (it's hard to tell from your sample), something like this should work:

```
pick = pd['longitude']>180
pd.loc[pick,'longitude'] = pd.loc[pick,'longitude'] - 360
```

The first line chooses the rows where longitude needs adjusting.  The second line does the math for only those rows.

Comment: note they're asking about xarray, not pandas :)